# What should be the exponent on the parameter to get the same solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Regarding the Boussinesq equations of motion:

[image: EOM]

I was reading a paper which stated the following:

[image: statement]

Shouldn't the $\alpha$ before the $t$ be $\alpha^{-1}$ instead? Could be a typo or maybe I am not thinking about this properly. It seems like a straightforward operation, what I did was substitute the second form in Eq 29a.

(I can provide link to paper if necessary but it is probably irrelevant, so I will omit for now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time derivatives transform as (given $t'=\alpha t$ where $t'$ is the rescaled time variable)
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}\frac{\partial t'}{\partial t}=\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}. $$
Spatial variables $x$ and $y$ stay unchanged, so 29b becomes, for example,
$$ \alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}\left(\alpha^2 \rho(x,y,t')\right)+\alpha \vec U\cdot\left(\alpha^2\nabla\rho\right)=0 $$
and you can see that both terms have a factor of $\alpha^3$, so $\rho$ and $\vec U$ still satisfy 29b.

29a will have a common factor of $\alpha^2$, and 29c will have a common factor of $\alpha$.

Comment: Can you just clarify why it is not possible to do $t \to \alpha t$, just as we did with the dependent variables (Example: $\rho \to \alpha^2 \rho$)? That is, why do we need the transformation you show in the first equation.

Comment: Because you're taking a derivative with respect to $\alpha t$, it's different to a derivative with respect to $t$. Maybe this wikipedia link will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables#Differentiation.